# How to load a 32bit DLL in a 64bit windows

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

I installed `Mozilla FireFox x64` in a 64bit windows, now I want to `LoadLibrary(mozglue.dll)` but I receive error number 193

`LoadLibrary(mozglue.dll)` works good in a 32bit windows with `Mozilla FireFox 86`

I use this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int main()
{
    HMODULE hndl;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    WCHAR errorBuff[MAX_PATH] = {};

    hndl = LoadLibraryW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\mozglue.dll");
    dwError = GetLastError();
    StringCbPrintfW(errorBuff, MAX_PATH, L"%d", dwError);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, errorBuff, L"GetLastError", MB_OK);
    FreeLibrary(hndl);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem with this code?

**Edit:**

I use:

`LoadLibraryExW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\mozglue.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);`

instead of:

`LoadLibraryW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\mozglue.dll");`

Now `GetLastError` returns 0 but `GetProcAddress` fails...

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <strsafe.h>


    typedef enum SECItemType {
        siBuffer = 0,
        siClearDataBuffer = 1,
        siCipherDataBuffer,
        siDERCertBuffer,
        siEncodedCertBuffer,
        siDERNameBuffer,
        siEncodedNameBuffer,
        siAsciiNameString,
        siAsciiString,
        siDEROID,
        siUnsignedInteger,
        siUTCTime,
        siGeneralizedTime
    };

    struct SECItem {
        SECItemType type;
        unsigned char *data;
        size_t len;
    };

    typedef enum SECStatus {
        SECWouldBlock = -2,
        SECFailure = -1,
        SECSuccess = 0
    };


    typedef struct PK11SlotInfoStr PK11SlotInfo;
    typedef SECStatus(*NSS_Init) (const char *);
    typedef SECStatus(*NSS_Shutdown) (void);
    typedef PK11SlotInfo * (*PK11_GetInternalKeySlot) (void);
    typedef void(*PK11_FreeSlot) (PK11SlotInfo *);
    typedef SECStatus(*PK11_Authenticate) (PK11SlotInfo *, int, void *);
    typedef SECStatus(*PK11SDR_Decrypt) (SECItem *, SECItem *, void *);

    PK11_GetInternalKeySlot PK11GetInternalKeySlot;
    PK11_FreeSlot PK11FreeSlot;
    PK11_Authenticate PK11Authenticate;
    PK11SDR_Decrypt PK11SDRDecrypt;
    NSS_Init fpNSS_INIT;
    NSS_Shutdown fpNSS_Shutdown;



    BOOL loadFunc()
    {
        HMODULE hndl;
        DWORD dwError = 0;
        WCHAR errorBuff[MAX_PATH] = {};
        BOOL retVal = FALSE;

        hndl = LoadLibraryExW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\mozglue.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
        dwError = GetLastError();
        StringCbPrintfW(errorBuff, MAX_PATH, L"%d", dwError);
        MessageBoxW(NULL, errorBuff, L"GetLastError", MB_OK);


        hndl = LoadLibraryExW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\nss3.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
        dwError = GetLastError();
        StringCbPrintfW(errorBuff, MAX_PATH, L"%d", dwError);
        MessageBoxW(NULL, errorBuff, L"GetLastError", MB_OK);

        if (hndl)
        {
            fpNSS_INIT = (NSS_Init)GetProcAddress(hndl, "NSS_Init");
            fpNSS_Shutdown = (NSS_Shutdown)GetProcAddress(hndl, "NSS_Shutdown");
            PK11GetInternalKeySlot = (PK11_GetInternalKeySlot)GetProcAddress(hndl, "PK11_GetInternalKeySlot");
            PK11FreeSlot = (PK11_FreeSlot)GetProcAddress(hndl, "PK11_FreeSlot");
            PK11Authenticate = (PK11_Authenticate)GetProcAddress(hndl, "PK11_Authenticate");
            PK11SDRDecrypt = (PK11SDR_Decrypt)GetProcAddress(hndl, "PK11SDR_Decrypt");
        }
        return !(!fpNSS_INIT || !fpNSS_Shutdown || !PK11GetInternalKeySlot || !PK11Authenticate || !PK11SDRDecrypt || !PK11FreeSlot);
    }



    int main()
    {
        if (loadFunc())
        {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"OK", L"", MB_OK);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"NO", L"", MB_OK);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Did you compile it for 64 bit? The mozglue you installed here most probably is 64 bit as the rest of Firefox, if your executable is 32 bit it cannot load it.

Comment: You can load a 32-bit DLL into a 32-bit ***process*** on 64-bit Windows, but you cannot load it into a 64-bit process. So you would have to install the 32-bit Firefox.

Comment: I compile it one time for 32 bit and one time for 64bit but both get error 193

Comment: I need to do this when a 64-bit Firefox is installed

Comment: You don't check to see if `hndl` is NULL or not. You should only have to check `GetLastError` if the returned handle was NULL. With that being said are you sure that when you compiled the test program with 64-bit code that you actually got error 193 when you ran it? Maybe you got another error?

Comment: I compiled the code as 64-bit in your question  (with path L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\mozglue.dll" ) and I received error 203. The error was meaningless because it did return a proper reference to a DLL in `hwndl` .

Comment: I edit my question, please take a look

Comment: If you are done with error 193 and got stuck at another problem, please accept the most helpful answer and ask another question.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Hi, I send you an email, please check your email.

Answer (score 3):

Your first issue is that 64-bit programs can't load 32-bit DLLs and 32-bit programs can't load 64-bit DLLs for the purposes of executing code. This is described in MSDN's [Process Interopability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384231(v=vs.85).aspx) information:

> You can run Win32-based applications on 64-bit Windows using an emulation layer. For more information, see Running 32-bit Applications.
>
> On 64-bit Windows, a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit dynamic-link library (DLL). Additionally, a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit DLL.

If you need to support both 32-bit programs and 64-bit the easiest way is to install the 32-bit version of the Mozilla DLLs (via a 32-bit Mozilla install) and you do the same for 64-bit Mozilla. By default 64-bit Mozilla should be placed in `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\` and 32-bit Mozilla in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\`. You'll need to account for the different directories when building a 64-bit application vs a 32-bit application  when loading DLLs like `mozglue.dll`

---

You don't check to see if `hndl` is NULL or not. You should only have to check `GetLastError` if the returned handle was NULL, not when it isn't NULL. Secondly calling `LoadLibraryExW` with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` allows you to load DLL resources, but doesn't allow you to retrieve the function addresses with `GetProcAddress`. This is documented in the MSDN Documentation for [LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx):

> LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE 0x00000002
>
> If this value is used, the system maps the file into the calling process's virtual address space as if it were a data file. Nothing is done to execute or prepare to execute the mapped file. Therefore, **you cannot call functions like** GetModuleFileName, GetModuleHandle or **GetProcAddress** with this DLL. Using this value causes writes to read-only memory to raise an access violation. Use this flag when you want to load a DLL only to extract messages or resources from it.

---

Keeping the ideas above in mind I compiled your code with a revised `loadfunc` and built it as a 64-bit application. When finished your program prints `OK` in a MessageBox:

```
BOOL loadFunc()
{
    HMODULE hndl;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    WCHAR errorBuff[MAX_PATH] = {};
    BOOL retVal = FALSE;

    hndl = LoadLibraryW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\mozglue.dll");
    // if the handle is NULL then check for an error otherwise proceed
    if (!hndl)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        StringCbPrintfW(errorBuff, MAX_PATH, L"%d", dwError);
        MessageBoxW(NULL, errorBuff, L"GetLastError", MB_OK);
        return TRUE;
    }

    hndl = LoadLibraryW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\nss3.dll");
    // if the handle is NOT NULL then try to retrieve the method addresses
    if (hndl)
    {
        fpNSS_INIT = (NSS_Init)GetProcAddress(hndl, "NSS_Init");
        fpNSS_Shutdown = (NSS_Shutdown)GetProcAddress(hndl, "NSS_Shutdown");
        PK11GetInternalKeySlot = (PK11_GetInternalKeySlot)GetProcAddress(hndl, "PK11_GetInternalKeySlot");
        PK11FreeSlot = (PK11_FreeSlot)GetProcAddress(hndl, "PK11_FreeSlot");
        PK11Authenticate = (PK11_Authenticate)GetProcAddress(hndl, "PK11_Authenticate");
        PK11SDRDecrypt = (PK11SDR_Decrypt)GetProcAddress(hndl, "PK11SDR_Decrypt");
    }
    // the handle was NULL if we get here so show the error
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        StringCbPrintfW(errorBuff, MAX_PATH, L"%d", dwError);
        MessageBoxW(NULL, errorBuff, L"GetLastError", MB_OK);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return !(!fpNSS_INIT || !fpNSS_Shutdown || !PK11GetInternalKeySlot || !PK11Authenticate || !PK11SDRDecrypt || !PK11FreeSlot);
}
```

For a 32-bit program you'd need to change the path in the code above to the 32-bit Mozilla directory as mentioned earlier and compile as an x86 32-bit application. The default path for the 32-bit code mentioned earlier would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\`

I downloaded the 64-bit version of Mozilla from this [download link](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-51.0.1-SSL&os=win64&lang=en-US) and the 32-bit Mozilla installation from [this link](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-stub&os=win&lang=en-US).

Answer (score 2):

You are either trying to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process, or a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process.  It can't be done.

I imagine that if you have 'Mozilla FireFox x64' that `mozglue.dll` is 64-bit - so you need to compile and link your test program as 64-bit.

Comment: I know, but I installed a x64 Firefox, and the mozglue that I try to load is the dll that create after installation...

Comment: So, what does dumpbin/dependency walker say your test exe is (32-bit or 64-bit?) and what does it say mozglue is?

Comment: LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE says "this DLL contains no code".  Obviously GetProcAddress won't work - you've told the OS the DLL contains no procedures.  You haven't answered my question about the bittedness of the exe and dl..