# How to link a 32-bit DLL for 64-bit WINE against 64-bit Linux libraries only?

Tags: dll, x86, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, wine

I am using WINE (on 64-bit Linux) to run a 32-bit Windows application which loads a DLL ([`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya)). I would like to re-write the DLL and compile it with `winegcc`/`winebuild` for that environment, without modifications to the original program. I am not interested in supporting 32-bit Linux hosts but the DLL itself needs to target 32-bit Windows as, as noted in the [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42371425), it is required for [process interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/process-interoperability):

> On 64-bit Windows, a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit dynamic-link library (DLL).
>
> Additionally, **a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit DLL**.

However, when building for 32-bit Windows, `winegcc` (using the `-m32` flag) produces an x86 "DLL-wrapping" shared object which links against other 32-bit versions of Linux libraries (*e.g.* `libwinecrt0.a`). This is not the desired behavior as it requires the Linux host to have those 32-bit libraries which hinders easy distribution of the DLL. Furthermore, trying to manually link against the 64-bit versions of the libraries is prevented by the linker itself with the expected error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: relocatable linking with relocations from
format elf64-x86-64 to format elf32-i386 is not supported
```

Now, I understand that there is an inherent difference in ISA (even ABI?) between x86 and amd64/x86_64 causing 32-bit Windows applications to be unable to load 64-bit DLLs and the GCC linker to refuse linking 32-bit Linux shared objects to 64-bit libraries. This incompatibility is the reason why modern CPUs are able to be placed in an "[x86 mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes)", allowing 32-bit code to run. That mode switching, in turn, requiring privileges that regular userspace programs do not have, means that having an x86_64-to-x86 compatibility layer in the libraries is not possible (see [*Why cannot 64-bit shared libraries be used by 32-bit code?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472201)); is that right? If not, how would it be done?

Having said that, I notice that 32-bit Windows applications are able to be run by 64-bit WINE without (AFAIK) requiring any 32-bit Linux libraries. Consequently, I guess that WINE performs that through its re-implementation of [WoW64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) and, by doing so, contains any "32-bit-ness" within the WINE environment. Is there then a way for me to exploit this in my DLL?

The point I am making here is that this is not a regular "calling 64-bit libraries from 32-bit code" problem, as it involves one (even two?) extra layer(s) on top of the OS, which I would like to somehow exploit. The options I have considered, but which do not meet all requirements, are:

- build the DLL with `winegcc -m32` makes `LoadLibrary` succeed but links against 32-bit Linux libraries
- build the DLL with `winegcc -m64` links against 64-bit Linux libraries but makes it impossible to `LoadLibrary` from 32-bit Windows
- build the DLL with MinGW (or any Windows-native compiler) leverages WoW64 so that no 32-bit Linux library is required but prevents me from using Linux code at all, which was the whole point of re-writing the library in the first place

What other options do I have? Wrapper code? Particular syscalls? Specific functionality within WINE? ...?